# How can I use two transitions with material ui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

What I'm trying to do is use `Fade` and `Slide` in the same component.

```
<Slide in={isValid} timeout={timeout} direction="left">                                
    <Fade in={isValid} timeout={timeout}>
        <Foo />
    </Fade>
</Slide>
```

But it doesn't work.

When `isValid` is true, it slides the component without the fade effect and when it's false, the component just blinks and disappears.

How can I make it work? I don't want to use `makeStyle`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I realized that if you wrap the transition in a `div` or other element to make it as a container, it will work.

```
<Slide in={isValid} timeout={timeout} direction="left">        
    <div> // adding this div will make it work                       
        <Fade in={isValid} timeout={timeout}>
            <Foo />
        </Fade>
    </div>
</Slide>
```

And then you can just create your own `Fade` component that wraps a `div`.

```
const MyFade = React.forwardRef(
  ({ children, in: In, timeout, ...otherProps }, ref) => {
    return (
      <div ref={ref} {...otherProps}>
        <Fade in={In} timeout={timeout}>
          {children}
        </Fade>
      </div>
    );
  }
);
```

Thanks to [@Ryan Cogswe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7495930/ryan-cogswell) that also helped in this.

Comment: Yes, [this is sufficient](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-fz93o). The complications in my answer stemmed from initially trying to get it to work without the extra div.

Comment: @RyanCogswell but you added an extra div in your answer, would it work if removed? (the div inside `Fade`)

Answer (score 8):

The [Slide](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.7.1/packages/material-ui/src/Slide/Slide.js#L123) and the [Fade](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.7.1/packages/material-ui/src/Fade/Fade.js#L50) components both change the `style.transition` property, so if they act on the same element they clobber portions of the other's work.

The way to get this to work is for them to act on **different** elements. Introducing a `div` between the two transitions gets the desired behavior.

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Switch from "@material-ui/core/Switch";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import Fade from "@material-ui/core/Fade";
import Slide from "@material-ui/core/Slide";
import FormControlLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    height: 180
  },
  container: {
    display: "flex"
  },
  paper: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    backgroundColor: "lightblue"
  },
  svg: {
    width: 100,
    height: 100
  },
  polygon: {
    fill: theme.palette.primary.main,
    stroke: theme.palette.divider,
    strokeWidth: 1
  }
}));

export default function SlideAndFade() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(false);

  const handleChange = () => {
    setChecked(prev => !prev);
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <FormControlLabel
        control={<Switch checked={checked} onChange={handleChange} />}
        label="Show"
      />
      <div className={classes.container}>
        <Slide in={checked} timeout={1000}>
          <div>
            <Fade in={checked} timeout={1000}>
              <Paper elevation={4} className={classes.paper}>
                <svg className={classes.svg}>
                  <polygon
                    points="0,100 50,00, 100,100"
                    className={classes.polygon}
                  />
                </svg>
              </Paper>
            </Fade>
          </div>
        </Slide>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Material demo]

Comment: Take a look at my answer, what do you think? I liked your answer, but maybe it's over complicated?

Comment: @Vencovsky I've simplified it now.